# Can a machine learning model be used as some kind of compression?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to understand how machine learning is working. I read a lot and now came into my mind that it could be missuses in a practical way. I also hope that this question is on topic here.

Please correct me if I have some wrong assumptions:

- All models require sample data
- The learning process is some kind of optimization of its functions aka neutrons
- The learning process is iterative to find the best values of the parameters to maximize the expected output of the neurons
- To make this process faster you do some kind of reduction of the data, so that in the end the neutrons do not need to look at every part of the input
- You split up the training data in two buckets to find out of the result became better for the optimization (I would call this verification, not sure how this is really called)
- If your verification data are bad or equal to the input data than the results can just be as good as your input data

If this is true or at least most parts I got this idea:
When I set the input data to the same as the output data, then the model is doing nothing, but for equal data I get always the same data right?

So when I train the model as in the table:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 5 |

Then the model would return PI based on the correct count of digits (of cause for non learned indexes that would be random)

I absolutely know that this makes no sense at all, but I'm just curious if I understand it correctly that you could *"compress"* data in a ML-Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a good bit of confusion in how you define Machine Learning:

- There are different types of learning: if the model is trained with data annotated with the "correct" answers, then it's supervised learning.
- There are many different "families" (methods) for supervised ML. Your description focuses on Neural Networks, but there are many others.
- Your last two steps probably refer to validation (during training) and/or evaluation (after training and on a separate test set), but it's not very clear.

Supervised ML can be summarized as follows:

- The goal is for the system to find a function $f$ which transforms an input $x$ (features) into an output $y$ (target variable)
- The system is provided with a sample of pairs $(x,y)$ (training data). Note that this sample is only a subset of the population data: after the training the system must be able to find $y$ for any input $x$, not only the values of $x$ seen in the training data.
- This is why the system must *generalize* from the data, i.e. find the patterns in $x$ which are useful to determine $y$. If the system doesn't generalize and only stores exactly which $x$ gives which $y$ then it cannot predict the answer $y$ for any value $x$ which was not seen in the training data, and that's useless.

In a sense the process of generalization can be seen as compressing the *knowledge* contained in the training data. However there are at least a couple major differences:

- The goal of compression is to represent a specific input $x$ using as little space as possible in a way which makes it possible to re-obtain the same $x$, possibly with some loss. The goal of supervised ML is to predict an output $y$ for *any* $x$. First $y \neq x$, but more importantly the ML cannot produce back the data it was trained with (in general, see exception just below).
- A ML model doesn't have to reduce the size of the training data. For example [instance-based learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance-based_learning) just stores all the instances in order to later use it for predicting.

Answer (score 2):

You're right I'm not sure if I followed exactly what you said, however for your overall question of can a Machine Learning model be used as a form of compression - yes!

A good example is an [**Autoencoder**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), which is a neural network that 'breaks down' the input into basic elements and then reconstructs the input using only the elements required.  This is formally know as *Dimensionality Reduction*.

Some of the practical applications are removing noise for example from images, which if you think about is removing data you don't need but preserving the overall look.  Much like traditional image compression, it won't look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly only the question in the title, because there is a good answer:
Yes: https://bellard.org/ts_server/ts_zip.html

> The ts_zip utility provided with the ts_server software can compress (and hopefully decompress) text files with Large Language Models.